# No-IP domain showing default router page

Tags: router, nat

I have create a domain using no-ip.com for my dynamic ip server. Now when I try to access this domain, its showing default router page.

I have tried to access it from different network as well as different computers.

Comment: It does not belong on Stackoverflow. It is not a programming or related question. Try asking on serverfault instead.

Comment: Going to have to agree with @Cheesebaron here, serverfault.com is where this question belongs. (and it's probably a duplicate). Flagging.

Comment: There is no question here.  It wouldn't do well on [SF] either.

Comment: For me it sounds like he wants to know how to configure his consumer-grade router to forward port 80 to a machine in his network.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would avoid putting that address here. Secondly you need to set up port forwarding for web/http (port 80) and disable the router's management console for external access (or at least change the port).